# Flexslider, show next slide

Tags: flexslider

I am using a nice slider found at http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

I want to change to the 2nd slide when you click a link which I positioned below the slider but not sure how this can be achieved & there is nothing on their site, does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your flexslider js, you will come across a function for animation.

```
 slider.flexAnimate = function(target, pause)
```

This is the function that will help you achieve what you wish to do. 
After the function ends, you can write:

```
yourFuntionName = slider.flexAnimate;
```

Call this function on clicking the link as yourFuntionName(1);

**or** simply call

```
slider.flexAnimate(1);
```

**or** for version 1.8 onwards:

```
$('#slider').flexslider(1);
```

*Note that slide 1 = target 0, slide 2 = target 1 and so on. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! This worked exactly as desired!

$(".trigger").click(function() {
 $('.flexslider').flexslider(1); 
});